# Subtracting dates in while loop with specific conditions

Tags: sql

I have such case.
Fact table looks like below:

```
ID  orders end_date         code
1   1      2022-10-10       ZTTS
2   1      2022-10-10       ZTTS12
3   1      2022-10-10       ZTTS
4   1      2022-10-10       ZTTS
5   1      2022-10-10       ZTTS12
6   1      2022-10-10       ZTTS
7   2      2022-10-10       ZTTS
8   2      2022-10-10       ZTTS
9   2      2022-10-10       ZTTS
10  2      2022-10-10       ZTTS
11  2      2022-10-10       ZTTS12
12  2      2022-10-10       ZTTS
```

Now business want's to re-schedule those orders and see end_date's with specific conditions.
For code ZTTS it should substract 2 days from end date starting at the end and for ZTTS12 - 12 days.

The expected result should be as follows

```
ID  orders end_date         code
1   1      2022-09-10       ZTTS
2   1      2022-09-12       ZTTS12
3   1      2022-09-24       ZTTS
4   1      2022-09-26       ZTTS
5   1      2022-09-28       ZTTS12
6   1      2022-10-10       ZTTS
7   2      2022-09-20       ZTTS
8   2      2022-09-22       ZTTS
9   2      2022-09-24       ZTTS
10  2      2022-09-26       ZTTS
11  2      2022-09-28       ZTTS12
12  2      2022-10-10       ZTTS
```

I was trying to do this in while

```
declare @data_zlecenie date
declare @days2 int = -2
declare @days12 int = -12
declare @iterator int = 1
declare @T int = (select MAX(id)-1 from dbo.tests)

declare @kod1 varchar(10) = 'ZTTS'
declare @kod2 varchar(10) = 'ZTTS12'

while @T >= @iterator /*1*/
begin 
            
    update dbo.tests set end_date = dateadd(day, @days2, end_date ) where ID = @T 
            
    set @T = @T - 1
                
    set @days2 = @days2 - 2 
                
end;
```

It works but only for subtracting 2 or 12 and for all orders (does not divide into orders).
Maybe there is some simpler way to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use `case` clause?
Something like

```sql
update dbo.test set end_date=dateadd(day,case 
when code='ZTTS' then -2
when code='ZTTS12' then -12
else 0
end,end_date)
```

Comment: The days subtracted needs to be cumulative for a given order # and start from the highest ID and work it's way back towards the lowest ID.

Comment: Yes, exacly. As i show in example